# Magento checkout page reorder checkout step

Tags: magento-1.9, php, zend-framework

I have install third party extension of Ipragmatech.
I want to make the step defined by this extension as default checkout step or 1st checkout step
i have made changes in

Ipragmatech/Checkoutstep/Block/Onepage.php
as

```
class Ipragmatech_Checkoutstep_Block_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage
{
    public function getSteps()
    {
        $steps = array();

        if (!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
            $steps['login'] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData('login');
        }

        //check that module is enable or not
        if (Mage::helper('checkoutstep')->isEnabled()) {
             $stepCodes = array('checkoutstep','billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
        }
        else {

            $stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
        }
        foreach ($stepCodes as $step) {
            $steps[$step] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData($step);
        }

        return $steps;
    }
    }
```

but code was not working properly by default it goes to Billing step

in default checkout step in `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block`  redefined as

```
public function getActiveStep()
  {
return $this->isCustomerLoggedIn() ? 'checkoutstep' : 'login';
```

}

after doing this step is being displayed in checkout step but not working
it default follows step as
  login->billing->shipping->checkoutstep(this step i want to be 1st open )->[image]

step is being displayed first but after shipping method this step get enabled.